# Pulling posts from an individual category to a post

Tags: wordpress, web, blogs, posts

I am trying to pull a a list of special offers posts to the special offers page on the website. The site is http://www.lansdownehotelcroydon.com/local-area/special-offers/ The post id is "specialoffers" But i cant seem to show the special offers on the page.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'special_offers', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
```

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
     ?>

```
        <div class="one_half">
            <div class="paddingAll">
            <h2><a href="/contact#wpcf7-f4-p43-o1"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="/contact#wpcf7-f4-p43-o1"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?></a>
            <div class="offercontent">
                <?php the_content();?>

            </div>

            </div>
            <a class="sp-enquiry" href="/contact#wpcf7-f4-p43-o1">Book Now</a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Please describe your problem precisely and what you have tried until now and how those tries failed...

Comment: "specialoffers"  is category slug of those posts ?

Comment: I am no wordpress expert, but I believe so.

Comment: paste your code here, please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'special_offers', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
```

for fetching the posts for a particular category.

Comment: I have already tried that, the special offers are meant to go into small boxes on the page.

Comment: <div class="sp-box">
            <div class="special_offers">
               
            <div class="one_half">
             <div class="paddingAll">
             <h2><a href="/contact#wpcf7-f4-p43-o1"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <a href="/contact#wpcf7-f4-p43-o1"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?></a>
                <div class="offercontent">
                <?php the_content();?>
    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="sp-enquiry" href="/contact#wpcf7-f4-p43-o1">Book Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: please show the query you have used before this code

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: Its "specialoffers" Or "special_offers" ?

Comment: special_offers
I have an image of what the page should look like but it isnt allowing me to add the image.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you set up your Custom Post Type, you may simply need to change:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'special_offers', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
```

to:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'special_offer', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
```

Custom post types should be set up and referred to in the singular when calling them in loops

Comment: adam could you please email me at lee@visionfive.co.uk